# One data point with multiple names

Tags: qgis, carto, datastructure

I am a beginner at mapping and I am wondering how best to structure a dataset I am working on. Ideally, I would like one data point for each city on my map, but I would also like to include alternative names for these cities. I would also like these alternative names to be searchable on the map.

Any advice on structuring my data?

I will either be using Carto or QGIS for this project.

Comment: Where do you see the problem? Have you tried something already? Why can't each data point have several attributes?

Comment: I tried a sample map in Carto for New York City (the data point) and had another column for alternate city names over time. When I searched "Mannahatta" (one of the alternate names) nothing happened. When I searched "Nieuw Nederland" (another alternate name) the search function in Carto brought me to current village in Curaçao with that name. How do I get it so the data point for New York City also brings searchers to the same point who type in Mannahatta, Nieuw Nederland, etc. I can't tell if this is about structuring my data or something about the search configuration in Carto. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

QGIS 3.0 has a search function called the [Locator Bar](http://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/3.0.0/#locator-bar) which allows you to select features by typing in an attribute value.
[image]

Then use the "zoom to selection" button to zoom the map to the selected feature.

Or you can use the Select Feature by Value tool:
[image]

Notice that it has a "zoom to features" button.

---

Set up your data with one attribute for the current name, one for an alternate name. If some cities have more than one alternate name, add additional alternate name attributes as needed.

You can also label your point features using one of the names, or concatenate all the names into one label.

Answer (score 1):

Search box in CARTO does not use your data but a standard geocoding service. To look for results in your data you need to use a category widget that allows to search on your column values and filter by that value. It won't zoom in to your results, though.

You have more details on how to use that widget on BUILDER on [this guide](https://carto.com/learn/guides/widgets/search-and-filter-category-values/)

[image]